# Twill cms login error message cURL error 28: Connection timed out after 1011 milliseconds

Tags: php, curl, content-management-system, twill

Does anyone know the awnser to this problem.

Im working with the twill cms and when i press login i'm faced with this error message :

> Error retrieving credentials from the instance profile metadata service. (cURL error 28: Connection timed out after 1011 milliseconds (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/) (View: C:\xampp81\htdocs\spacewebs.nl\vendor\area17\twill\views\layouts\dashboard.blade.php)

what can i do ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Twill 2.x the default storage provider for media library uploads is Amazon S3. If you haven't configured your environment variables with credentials for an S3 bucket, this error happens.

Of course you do not have to use S3 to be able to use Twill, and in the upcoming Twill 3 we are now defaulting to local, not remote storage.

You can solve this by setting the following in your `.env` file:

```
MEDIA_LIBRARY_ENDPOINT_TYPE=local
FILE_LIBRARY_ENDPOINT_TYPE=local
```

To get quicker support from the Twill maintainers and community in the future, I would suggest you join our [Discord](https://discord.link/twill) or submit an issue or post a discussion on [GitHub](https://github.com/area17/twill).